# Subquery with case in SELECT using Yii2 ActiveRecord

Tags: yii2

Is it possible to convert this kind of SQL into ActiveRecord query in Yii2:

```
SELECT a.id, 
    case length(a.id)
            when 6 then (select region_name from region where id = concat(left(a.id,2),'0000'))
            when 5 then (select region_name from region where id = concat(left(a.id,1),'0000'))
    end as prov,
    case length(a.id)
            when 6 then (select region_name from region where id = concat(left(a.id,4),'00'))
            when 5 then (select region_name from region where id = concat(left(a.id,3),'00'))
    end as kab,
   (select region_name from region where id = a.id) as kec
FROM region as a 
WHERE a.region_name LIKE '%kamb%'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absulatly convert this into query builde

```
$query = new \yii\db\Query;
$query->from("region as a ");
$query->select(new \yii\db\Expression("a.id, 
    case length(a.id)
            when 6 then (select region_name from region where id = concat(left(a.id,2),'0000'))
            when 5 then (select region_name from region where id = concat(left(a.id,1),'0000'))
    end as prov,
    case length(a.id)
            when 6 then (select region_name from region where id = concat(left(a.id,4),'00'))
            when 5 then (select region_name from region where id = concat(left(a.id,3),'00'))
    end as kab,
    (select region_name from region where id = a.id) as kec"));
$query->andWhere(['like', 'a.region_name', 'kamb']);
echo $query->createCommand()->rawSql;
```

In case of **ActiveRecord query** replace select section as above

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, i am new in yii2, how i can get  or show the query result

Comment: $query->all(); for all record and $query->one() for single record

Comment: i have add `$query->all()`, but when i print_r($query) the query result not show, just `yii\db\Query Object ( [select] => Array ( [0] => yii\db\Expression Object ( [expression] => a.id, case length(a.id) when 6 then (select region_name from region where id = concat(left(a.id,2),'0000')) when 5 then (select region_name from region where id = concat(left(a.id,1),'0000')) end as prov, case length(a.id) when 6 then (select region_name from region where id = concat(left(a.id,4),'00')) when 5 then (select region_name from region where id = conc...`

Comment: print this line print_r($query->all());

Comment: or $result = $query->all(); than print result print_r($result)